# How to browse to destination folder when clicking on download notification

Tags: android, android-notifications

From my App, I am downloading some music files and saving them in a folder. In notification panel download progress is shown. When download completes, if notification is clicked, my android device should directly browse to destination folder, similar to "go to folder" on PCs after any download finishes.

I tried it from below code, but it is not working. It is just opening the app.

```
public class Temp extends Activity {

    String[] link;
    String[] items;
    String song_link;
    String song_name;
    int song_index;
    int link_index;
    String url_link;
    Exception error;
    private ProgressBar mProgress;
    long total = 0;
    boolean downloadStatus = false;
    ProgressDialog progressBar;  
    private Handler progressBarHandler = new Handler();  
    int progressBarStatus = 0; 
    Uri selectedUri;
    Intent intent;
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent;



    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder= 
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("My notification")
            .setContentText("Downloading");
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager;

    int id=1;


    private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Long> {
         protected Long doInBackground(String... urls) {
             mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            // mProgress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
             url_link = urls[0];
                 try {
                    /* runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"link: "+url_link,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    });*/
                     int count;
                     URL url = new URL(url_link);
                    URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
                    conexion.connect();
                    // this will be useful so that you can show a typical 0-100% progress bar
                    final int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();

                    // Download the file
                    InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
                   // String name = "first.mp3";

                         File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                                    Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC), "Vaishnav Songs");
                            if (!folder.mkdirs()) {
                                Log.e(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE, "Directory not created");
                            }

                         File filename = new File(folder,song_name);
                         OutputStream output = null;

                             output = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filename));

                    byte data[] = new byte[1024];


                  mBuilder.setContentTitle(song_name);
                  int percentage;
                  id = song_index*10 + link_index;
                    while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                        total += count;
                        // publishing the progress....
                     //  publishProgress((int)(total*100/lenghtOfFile) );
                        percentage = (int)(total*100/lenghtOfFile) ;
                        if(percentage%5 ==0){
                           new Thread(new Runnable() {
                              public void run() {
                                 mBuilder.setProgress(100, (int)total*100/lenghtOfFile, false);
                                // Displays the progress bar for the first time.
                                mNotificationManager.notify(id, mBuilder.build());

                              }
                          }).start();
                        }



                        output.write(data, 0, count);
                    }

                    output.flush();
                    output.close();
                    input.close();
                    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
                   new Thread(new Runnable() {
                      public void run() {
                         mBuilder.setContentText("Download complete")
                        // Removes the progress bar
                                .setProgress(100,100,false);
                        mNotificationManager.notify(id, mBuilder.build());

                      }
                  }).start();



                     }
                     catch (Exception e) {
                        error = e;
                         runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error: "+error,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            }
                        });
                    }





                 // Escape early if cancel() is called
               //  if (isCancelled()) break;


             return total;
         }

         protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
             progressBarStatus = progress[0];




         }

         protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
            /* Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Downloaded "+result+" bytes",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/
             Intent intent = getIntent();
             finish();
             //startActivity(intent);
     }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         selectedUri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                    Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC) + "/"+"Vaishnav Songs"+"/");
          intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
          intent.setDataAndType(selectedUri, "resource/folder");
          resultPendingIntent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(
                this,
                0,
                intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            );

        song_name = (String) getIntent().getExtras().getString("songName");
        song_link = (String) getIntent().getExtras().getString("songLink");
        song_index = getIntent().getIntExtra("songIndex",0);
        link_index = getIntent().getIntExtra("position",0);
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Download started. Check progress in notification panel",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        //new DownloadFilesTask().execute(song_link);
         DownloadFilesTask task = new DownloadFilesTask();
            task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR,song_link);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Discover this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html
You can try add `setContentIntent(PendingIntent intent)` to your notification with action for File manager opening.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. But this i know and already using in the code. May be I am wrong at creating intent for opening a folder. can you suggest something for it.